# Using geometry nodes rotate a displacement texture around object

Tags: displacement, geometry-nodes

With the displacement modifier you cannot free rotate the displacement texture around an object it is limited to specific axis.

I want to use geometry nodes to rotate my displacement textures around objects?

Is this possible?

Comment: Apply rotation in sequence for each axis you want to rotate around.

Comment: @MartyFouts could you elaborate a little ?

Comment: for example, first rotate on the X axis, and then feed the result of that rotation to another rotation, but on the Y axis.  This is how Euler rotation actually works.

Comment: @MartyFouts I haven't been able to get your suggestion working, Would you be able to provide an example if you have time ?